# Simple Injector and Cookies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, simple-injector

How I can create instance for per-request lifescope with cookie's data as parameter?

For example:

```
container.Register<ISampleRepository>(() => 
    new SampleRepository(
        container.GetInstance<ApplicationDbContext>(), 
        request.Cookie["Token"]));
```

Comment: Cookies are *runtime* data that are *user specific* (and already tied to the request). Dependency Injection is something that happens 1 time at application startup for all users in the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). It makes absolutely no sense to have a user's cookie as an input to your application configuration. Perhaps it would be better if you describe what it is you are trying to achieve with your cookie.

Comment: I fully agree with @NightOwl888. Although with using the request data directly in your controller your're violating DIP. You need an application specific abstraction, but in the implementation of this abstraction there is no reason at all to inject the request data. Just use it directly there.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. 
I think I need describe the problem more detail.

System has some kind of user state which is kept in cookies.
All repositories are use that state for "logger".
Repositories are creating per request in controllers' constructors by using SimpleInjector.
Of course, I can set a user state for controllers' repositories after controller has been created. 
But I would be detach that code from controller and move it to dependecy injector. I thought that SimpleInjector provided the per-request handler, and I will be able to override it.
I hope I explained correctly.

Comment: You'll find the answer to your problem in [this blog post](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

Comment: Thank you Steven. This is what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As NightOwl888 stated in his comment:

> Cookies are runtime data that are user specific (and already tied to the request). Dependency Injection is something that happens 1 time at application startup for all users in the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). It makes absolutely no sense to have a user's cookie as an input to your application configuration. Perhaps it would be better if you describe what it is you are trying to achieve with your cookie.

The problem you are having with the right way to solve this is described fully in this [blog post](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).